# Visual Studio 2017 installer fails to install KB2533623

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2017, windows-update, vsinstaller

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2017 Community via web installer on my Windows 7 laptop and it fails, returning me this log:

**dd_setup_..._error.log** (translated into English from me, since it was in German)

```
Package "WindowsUpdates.KB2533623,version=15.0.26711.1,chip=x64" could not be installed.
    Search-URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=WindowsUpdates.KB2533623;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1168
    Details
        Command executed: "C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe" /online /quiet /norestart /add-package /packagepath:"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\462b07d7-22c4-4fb6-8bd8-78e9e210c711\Windows6.1-KB2533623-x64.cab" /logPath:"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170916213606_141_WindowsUpdates.KB2533623.log"
        Code returned: 1168
        Codedetails returned: Element not found.
```

KB2533623 is not installed at my Laptop, so I tried to install KB2533623 x64 by myself, but it's rejecting with the words "The update is not applicable to your computer".

After some research I found SCCMENTOR who is claiming [KB2533623 is superseded by KB2758857](https://sccmentor.com/2013/07/30/kb2533623-superseded-by-kb2758857/), so I tried to uninstall KB2758857, first. There was an error that I could not uninstall all updates. Repeating the step in a local system CMD with `wusa /uninstall /kb:2758857` returned 0x80070490. [Microsoft suggests to scan the system for corrupt files with `sfc /scannow`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/958044/windows-update-error-0x80070490), so I did. It found some errors and fixed them.

I repeated `wusa /uninstall /kb:2758857` and it returned 0x80070bc9. Then I restarted and tried it another time and it gives me 0x80070490, again.

I'm not sure I'm on the right path, maybe KB2533623 is not the problem here. How can I fix the problem, so the Visual Studio installer is able to install KB2533623 that is required by so many components of the suite? If KB2533623 is really superseded by KB2758857, why the installer tries to install KB2533623 at all, if KB2758857 is already installed on my laptop?

Comment: @Hans, this [appears to be a known issue that MS are working on](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96395/vs-2017-install-fails-because-missing-windows61-kb.html).

Comment: share the DISM.log and CBS.log from C:\Windows\Logs

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here is my current dism.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1vl0a919e6dtu4/dism.log?dl=0

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you for pointing this out. It's good to see MS is not ignoring the problem, however I need to find a workaround, because I need Visual Studio 2017 on my Laptop or I cannot continue my work on trips.

Comment: you miss always parts of drivers (inf files from C:\Windows\Inf). Reinstall all drivers and look what happens.

Comment: My only idea is to see if you can fake the installation of KB2533623 somehow (perhaps you could ask on Super User if anyone knows how to make Windows think an update is installed?) ... or perhaps you could remove the dependency on it in the VS2015 installer, perhaps that would be as simple as finding the XML file that references it and taking out the relevant lines?

Comment: I think the only *reliable* method would be to reinstall the laptop and make sure you manually install KB2533623 before installing any other updates.  That could be a lot of work though, depending on how much software the laptop already has.  Perhaps you could install a virtual machine instead?

Comment: I tried a few ways to force feed that KB or make it skip. I eventually tried to update to windows 10, but that ended up burning up my laptop. New laptop doesnt have Win 7, so no more problem.

Comment: have you reinstalled all drivers for your hardware? can you now install the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft fixed it in [Visual Studio 2017 15.5 Preview 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes#15.5.0%20Preview%203)

> - [Visual Studio 2017 15.3 installation fails with „Failed to install WindowsUpdates.KB2533623“ error message](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94800/cannot-get-visual-studio-2017-to-install-properly-1.html).
> - [Visual Studio 2017 install fails due to missing Windows6.1-KB2533623-x64.cab](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96395/vs-2017-install-fails-because-missing-windows61-kb.html).

So wait for the Final of the Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 and use the updated installer.

Comment: Yep, seems so. Well, I already moved on to Windows 10 on my Laptop and now I can install VS2017 without problems, but this cannot be the solution. Microsoft is way too slow on those critical bugs. It's a blocker that deserves a hotfix. Whatsoever, the problem will be solved.

Comment: [Microsoft made the mistake to check for a KB number](https://superuser.com/a/1209007/174557) and not for a file version number. this update is very old and already replaced by newer ones and diskcleanup removed it to reduce winsxs size.

Answer (score 0):

​Hello people!

I had the same problem, and I found that the KB2533623 superseded by KB2758857.
I checkout if this update was installed in my PC. You can check it running this command:

*wmic qfe list | find "2758857"*

This will show something like this if it was installed:

*http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2758857 MyMachine  Security Update KB2758857 AUTORIDADE NT\SISTEMA 9/2/2016*

So, I removed it with this command:

*wusa /uninstall /kb:2758857*

After this I can install with success the visual studio 2017.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but as stated in my question, I cannot uninstall KB2758857. I hope it helps other people at least.

Comment: Hi, I had this error trying to uninstall from the Control "Panel / Programs and Features". And I run this [link]http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/C/9/6C970550-32AB-4235-9CDD-7FC9DD848BBB/WindowsUpdate.diagcab[/link] to try to fix the corrupted updates. And after I ran this command and worked.

Comment: No sorry, this did not work. It claimed to fix some updates but I got the 0x80070490 error "Element not found" when executing the command. However, the wmic command has shown the entry.